# Any 12 or 14 v 100amp voltage regulator it?

Tags: transistors, voltage-regulator, linear-regulator

I have searched the Internet but didn't find one, can anybody please suggest me any regulator ic that is 12 or 14 volts and can bear upto 100 amps.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany i am trying to make and external voltage regulator for my car because i cannot find new alternator in my country and i know it's voltage regulator is bad so i am gonna make my own but with a small fan on it too that can cool the regulator.

Comment: Are any of the 6 diodes blown in the alternator What V , I do you reckon comes from alternator?

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt no diodes are working correctly as there is not AC current on output.

Comment: no output?   Short field winding to gnd test done?  You dont get AC , rather rectified 3 phase DC

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt what i meant was yes every diode is working fine because there is not AC output on the end.

Comment: answer my questions V,I and field gnd test result. SHould be migrated to Auto repair DIY fix not EE design

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt no i didn't done that yet.

Comment: then do that first, if you have no idea how it works, find out, then fix is easy.  Grounding Field pin to gnd gives max current out then check V and if scope, and check ripple for 3 phases.  14.2=ideal

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem!

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a worthwhile pursuit. Car alternator regulators work by varying the alternator field current to yield a stable output voltage when the engine is running. The field current of an alternator is only a few amperes, and the alternator takes less engine horsepower (and less fuel) to operate when the alternator is not supplying much current.

Running flat-out at full cruising speed could waste a very large amount of power, and would be impractical to heat sink I should think.

It may be practical to replace the voltage regulator with a homebrew circuit, [here](http://www.bdtic.com/download/ST/FL94XX1106.pdf) is the ST flyer on their monolithic "voltage regulator" chips. Note that they do NOT handle the 100A or anything like that, they modulate the alternator field current as I said above.

[image]